# How to add material icon in the placeholder of input tag

Tags: html, input, placeholder, google-material-icons

i have my input tag as per the following

```
 <input type="text" placeholder="search place../>
```

I want to add a material icon `<i class="medium material-icons">location_on</i>` into the placeholder with those caption

can anyone please tell me how to do it? I already have included the material icon link stylesheet in HTML file

```
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score -5):

Try this :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/solid.css">

<input
  type="text"
  placeholder="&#xf689; Search place..."
  style="padding: 5px; font-family: Arial, 'Font Awesome 5 Free';"
/>
```

Hope it helps, just play around with some padding and css to make it nicer